# GitHub: Is it possible to collaborate with someone on a private gist?

Tags: git, github

I have a private gist. If I send the URL to a friend he can view it, but cannot edit it, unless he forks it.

Is there a way to edit it directly without forking it?

Comment: Apparently no, have a look here: http://www.focustheweb.com/2015/04/06/a-basic-collaboration-workflow-on-gist.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

2010: I am not sure it is possible.
To make a gist public (which is not what you want, but illustrates the lack of management features around gist), the [only solution was to re-post it](http://groups.google.com/group/github/browse_thread/thread/199f8312fa7f8036).

There doesn't seem to be a GUI for adding public ssh key for collaborators, like there is for a GitHub project.

---

Since my original answer in 2010, the ability to [fork a gist](https://help.github.com/en/github/writing-on-github/forking-and-cloning-gists#forking-gists) (as mentioned in [Avi Flax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7012/avi-flax)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24316203/6309)) was added (around 2014-2015).

> Each gist indicates which forks have activity, making it easy to find interesting changes from coworkers or complete strangers.

[image: Gist forks -- https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/gist/gist_forks.png]

See for instance "[A basic collaboration workflow on Gist](http://giovanni.curlybrackets.it/2015/04/06/a-basic-collaboration-workflow-on-gist.html)" (Apr. 2015) from  [Giovanni Cappellotto](http://giovanni.curlybrackets.it/about.html) ([`potomak`](https://github.com/potomak) on GitHub).

There is [no direct pull request supported though](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8767309/6309) (still valid in 2020).

Answer (score 26):

No. Your friend should fork the repo, and make her changes there.

You can then merge in your friend’s commits by:

1. Clone your gist repo locally
2. Add your friend’s fork as a remote

   1. e.g. if your friend is named Cindy: `git remote add-url cindy https://gist.github.com/cindy/df03bdacaef75a80f310`
3. Fetch your friend’s commits: `git fetch cindy/master`
4. Merge your friend’s changes into your repo: `git merge cindy/master`
5. Push the changes back to GitHub: `git push origin/master`

Answer (score 3):

Avi's approach is right, but the commands did not work for me. Using the same example Avi started, after I cloned my repo, I ran these commands from inside the gist repo directory:

```
$ git remote add cindy https://gist.github.com/cindy/df03bdacaef75a80f310
$ git fetch cindy master
$ git merge cindy/master
$ git push origin master
```

I wrote up a more detailed process for collaborating on gists [here](http://cobwwweb.com/collaborate-on-github-gist).

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. However, there is a way to easily re-post the Gist. It's explaned in here: http://chris.dzombak.name/blog/2011/05/making-private-gist-public.html

**UPDATE**

You can now make gists public/private. Github implemented this feature some time ago.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Thanks, I modified my answer. It aims to show an alternative way.

Comment: I want to remove my downvote w/out upvoting (sadly not possible) since you did amend what you mean, but now it's just a slightly less informative dupe of the accepted answer posted 3 years ago. Sorry!